# Spring MVC : new action ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I want to add a new action to an existing controller, and re-run the project, the new action is ignored, but old actions work. I tried to restart Eclipse, reboot. The action I want to add:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="dashboard.htm")
public ModelAndView dashboard(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    return new ModelAndView("General/dashboard");
}
```

Architecture of the project :

[image]

Full code of the controller :

```java
@Controller
public class UtilController extends MultiActionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="dashboard.htm")
    public ModelAndView dashboard(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        return new ModelAndView("General/dashboard");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="register.htm")
    public ModelAndView register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        return new ModelAndView("General/register");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="registerValidate.htm")
    public ModelAndView registerValidate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            Learner l = new Learner();
            l.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            l.setForname(request.getParameter("firstname"));
            l.setSurname(request.getParameter("lastname"));

            //LearnerService.
            SendEmail.sendMail("Votre insription sur le site AeroSafety a été effectuée avec succès.", request.getParameter("email"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("General/register");
    }
}
```

My dispatcher :

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/resources/img/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/lib/**" location="/resources/lib/"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

My web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PermisMVC</display-name>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I navigate to /dashboard.htm, I got this error :

> juin 15, 2016 11:43:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
>       AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/JEEProjetPermis/dashboard.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

I don't know why Eclipse doesn't fetch the new actions in this controller.

I'm sure I'm missing something. Let me know if you need another info / file.

Comment: which URL do you use?

Comment: My project is called JEEProjetPermis, and I call : 'http://localhost:8080/JEEProjetPermis/dashboard.htm'